# ZF2 - Adding pages to navigation from ViewHelper

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I'm creating a dynamic navigation which content is obtained by URL. To this I've created a ViewHelper in which one I work with my URL and prepare it to create the pages to my navigation.

```
    foreach($associativeArrayUrl as $key => $value) {
        $page = new MVC(array(
            'label' => $key,
            'route' => 'extranet/'.$key,
            'params' => array('paramid'.$key => $value),
        ));
        array_push($pages, $page);
    }

    $container->addPages($pages);

    foreach ($container as $page) {
        echo '---- ' . $page->label;
        echo '----' . $page->getHref();
    }
```

$associativeArrayUrl contains the following (for example):

```
array (size=2)
  'center' => string '10' (length=2)
  'education' => string '15' (length=2)
```

The problem is when I do the  `$page->getHref();` It does not show anything. What is the problem and how can I solve it??